# T-SQL like SELECT in INSERT query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with below structre

```
session
-----
Id
name
Active
```

I have another table with a foreign key to the first one

```
DocsMaster
------
Id
SessionId [freign key with session table]
Name
Description
```

I want to write a sql patch to insert some default values to the `DocsMaster` table and I am writing below statements

```
INSERT INTO `DocsMaster` (SessionId, Name, Description) 
VALUES (1,'Registration Certificate',' Scanned copy of reg certificate');

INSERT INTO `DocsMaster` (SessionId, Name, Description) 
VALUES (1,'Attestation Certificate',' Scanned copy of  certificate');

INSERT INTO `DocsMaster` (SessionId, Name, Description) 
VALUES (1,'Safety Certificate',' Scanned copy of  certificate');

INSERT INTO `DocsMaster` (SessionId, Name, Description)   
VALUES (1,'additional Certificate',' Scanned copy of  certificate');
```

Can I make a t-SQL statement for `sessionId`

```
SELECT Id 
FROM session 
WHERE Active = 1;
```

and use this id for insert statements? [ more or less similar to t-SQL ]

Comment: This question looks the same as asked here. [mysql insert value from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226585/mysql-insert-values-from-another-table-into-one-column). Please follow the link.